# Linear Programming with bounds on magnitude

Tags: nonlinear-programming, linear-programming, quadratic-programming

I have a set of halfplanes $H$, and a target vector $T$. My goal is to find the vector $v$ closest (2-norm) to vector $T$, such that $v$ is in the intersection of all of the halfplanes.

This can be reduced to a simple linear program, as each constraint on a halfplane can be represented as $ax+by\le c$, and the optimization function is $||T-v||_2$ (Technically, quadratic programming on linear constraints)

However, I would like to introduce an additional constraint of magnitude $M$ on $v$: $||v||_2 < M$. This constraint is the quadratic inequality $v_x^2 + v_y^2 \le M^2$

Are there currently methods that allow for addressing this optimization problem? It might also be interesting to consider a lower-bound $m \le ||v||_2$ as well, but that may be more difficult.

Comment: This is a convex nonlinear problem called quadratically constrained quadratic problem. You can use any convex optimization library (e.g. cvxopt) to solve it efficiently. The lower bound constraint will introduce nonconvexity.